# Is the tense correct in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, tenses, modal-verbs

Is this sentence correct grammatically?

> He must have seen my jet ski and became suspicious.

or should it be:

> He must have seen my jet ski and become suspicious.

Please note that the sentence was meant to refer to the past. I am most curious if "must have" has to be used in the second phrase, like this:

> He must have seen my jet ski and must have become suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'He must have seen my jet ski and become suspicious' is correct.

Phrases like 'must have', 'could have' etc are a special (*modal*) case of *Perfect Infinitives*, which take the form (verb) + have + past participle. The past participle of become is simply 'become', which is why that sentence is correct - 'became' is simple past.

There's no need for a second must have. It's not *technically* wrong, but it's redundant and doesn't read well. If we're already in that tense, the assumption is that we're going to stay in it.

Convoluted answer that probably won't help much or make much sense if you're not a language student, but short answer: It's correct.

Comment: What if the speculation is only about the seeing and the becoming suspicious is known. Then: "He must have seen my jet ski [and he] became suspicious, " with the bit in brackets abbreviated, seems ok.

Comment: If you really don't want the "must have" to go with the suspiciousness, you have to make some separation to prevent people from doing the linking.  For example, "He must have seen my jet ski, since he looked at me suspiciously."